# How to fit a CSS gradient in a container's height?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a CSS background gradient for my website's header and this has been bothering me for hours now. Let's say I have the following code:

```css
html, body, div#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

div#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /* IE10+ */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #0094FF 100%);
  /* Mozilla Firefox */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #0094FF 100%);
  /* Opera */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #0094FF 100%);
  /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100, #0094FF));
  /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #0094FF 100%);
  /* W3C Markup */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #FFFFFF 0%, #0094FF 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="http://www.poweruser-studios.tk/" hreflang="en-US">
        <img id="site-logo" src="http://www.poweruser-studios.tk/assets/imagesets/site-logo.png" alt="Official Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I strive to create responsive design for my site I am working with percent widths/heights. So if `25%` of the `height` is `62px` for my screen, I get a gradient that is `165px` long. That is not what I want. I want the gradient to fit the `header` div and not go outside of its bounds. So if the height of the `header` is 62px, then the gradient should resize to be 62px long as well. But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I'm using HTML Doctor CSS reset.

Comment: If you create a working demo of your problem, (snippet or fiddle), it will be easier to help you

Comment: @vals Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: have you tried setting min-height for `div#header` ?

Comment: The gradient does not extend out of the header - https://jsfiddle.net/amknbjbf/

Comment: @Paulie_D No, it does. Here is a link to my site: http://www.poweruser-studios.tk/
Notice all the space between the 2 long black `border-bottom` lines. Tested in the newest version of Firefox.

Comment: For me, both the fiddle and the site are ok, both in Chrome and FF

Comment: @vals But what? Can't you see the space between the 2 lines??

Comment: Header occupies 25% of the space, end at the lower of the 2 lines, and is filled by the gradient. The upper line is from the logo, and doesn't play any role here

Comment: Actually, yes. But when I hover over the `header` div with the inspector it says `62px` height. But when I close the inspector and take a screenshot of the screen I can clearly see in image editor that the gradient is `165px` long. That's what made me ask this question in the first place.

Comment: The height that you are seeing is most probably the one from the logo and not the one from the header